# How to avoid short-circuited evaluation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, design-patterns, boolean

I need to execute both sides of an `&&` statement, but this won't happen if the first part returns `false`. Example:

```
function doSomething(x) {
    console.log(x);
}

function checkSomething(x) {
    var not1 = x !== 1;
    if (not1) doSomething(x);

    return not1;
}

function checkAll() {
    return checkSomething(1)
        && checkSomething(3)
        && checkSomething(6)
}

var allValid = checkAll(); // Logs nothing, returns false
```

The problem here is that `doSomething(x)` should log 3 and 6, but because `checkSomething(1)` returns `false`, the other checks won't be called. ***What is the easiest way to run all the checks and return the result?***

I know I could save all the values in variables and check those subsequently, but that does not look very clean when I have a lot of checks. I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: `I know I could save all the values in variables and check those subsequently` You already know the answer, unfortunately it's not very pretty as you state.

Comment: `return [checkSomething(1), checkSomething(2), checkSomething(3)];` ???

Comment: In ES6 you could do `return [checkSomething(1), checkSomething(2), checkSomething(3)].every(a => a);`.

Comment: Why do you need to know the result of all the checks? Doesn’t the `return` statement imply that you want to know whether _all_ checks return `true`? Then you also don’t need to evaluate all the checks… If you want to get the result of each check individually, then use the suggestion with the array literal from A.Wolff.

Comment: I'm really confused getting what is expected behaviour here...

Comment: Your `checkSomething` handles two separate tasks at the same time which is generally bad practice and leads to problems like this. Depending on what the actual use case is, if `doSomething` has to run twice you should do that task separately instead of relying on it being a consistent side effect of `checkSomething`.

Comment: The point of short circuiting is that once the outcome of the logic expression is known, the following parts of the expression will not change the outcome so why run them.  Is that not the case for you?  So, once you find a `false` value, the overall result of three `&&` operations can never be `true` so why execute them?  Unless you have side effects in those parts of the expression (which is an evil way to code).  Fix your code rather than code this way.

Comment: @Juhana I don't think seperating `checkSomething` will solve this problem, because then I would still need to store each return value in a variable and run additional checks on those

Comment: @Duncan BUT what are you expecting `checkAll()` to return???

Comment: @A.Wolff The same as it returns now, the problem is that the `doSomething`s must be executed, which they don't at the moment

Comment: No, it would definitely solve this problem. You don't need a variable for each return value, you need only one flag that checks if at least one of them has returned false.

Comment: @Juhana An example would be nice

Comment: `var valid = true; for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { if( !checkSomething(i) { valid = false; } }  return valid;`

Comment: @Duncan Then i'd just quote: `Depending on what the actual use case is, if doSomething has to run twice you should do that task separately instead of relying on it being a consistent side effect of checkSomething`

Comment: @Juhana That would work with the given example, although the `checkSomething` can be different functions in my scenario

Comment: @Duncan See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @A.Wolff What `doSomething` should do is depending on the parameter of `checkSomething` (`x`), so I don't see how I could seperate that

Comment: [Please show your actual code.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) It's impossible to help if you keep adding more requirements every time.

Comment: @Duncan I meant ask question regarding your former issue, not the workaround you think would fix it. That's was my point.

Comment: @Juhana The actual code is to big and complicated to understand without a lot of explanation, but my example and additional explanation covers most of my problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a single &.  That is a bitwise operator.  It will execute all conditions and then return a bitwise sum of the results.

```
 function checkAll() {
    return checkSomething(1)
      & checkSomething(2)
      & checkSomething(3)
 }
```

Comment: This will return `1` or `0`, not `true` or `false`, but it seems like a productive direction.

Comment: `return !!(checkSomething(1)
      & checkSomething(2)
      & checkSomething(3))` to get boolean

Comment: better `return !!(checkSomething(1) | checkSomething(2) | checkSomething(3))`

Comment: That’s OR, @Thomas.

Answer (score 7):

You can multiply the comparison result and cast it to boolean.

```js
function checkSomething(x) {
    var not1 = x !== 1;
    if (not1) alert(x);
    return not1;
}

function checkAll() {
    return !!(checkSomething(1) * checkSomething(2) * checkSomething(3));
}

document.write(checkAll());
```

Or take some array method:

```
function checkAll() {
    return [checkSomething(2), checkSomething(2), checkSomething(3)].every(Boolean);
}
```

Comment: Why would you multiply when you could use the `&` operator? That way it would still read as "something AND something AND something"...

Comment: then use a bitwise or `|`

Comment: The array method worked best for me, TypeScript did not seem to like the others

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to my own question 2,5 years later I can agree with the people in the comments on how bad this code is by being based on side effects and therefore violating the single responsibility principle.

I just want to provide a proper solution for people visiting this page with the same question.

```
function doSomething(x) {
    console.log(x);
}

function checkSomething(x) {
    return x !== 1;
}

var values = [1, 3, 6];
var validValues = values.filter(checkSomething); // -> [3, 6]

validValues.forEach(doSomething); // -> Logs 3 and 6
var allValid = validValues.length === values.length; // false
```

As you can see, the `checkSomething` function now only does one thing: check something. The `doSomething` logic runs separately *after* all the checks are done.

A function should always either *do something* or *return something*, not both. Of course there are exceptions to this, but it is a good rule of thumb. This makes the code more predictable, testable and understandable.

Now, if at some point I want to check if all values are valid without "doing something", I can actually do this...

```
var allValid = checkSomething(1) && checkSomething(3) && checkSomething(6);
```

...without having to worry about side effects.

**Conclusion: You don't want to avoid short circuited evaluation**