# disabled on button does not evaluate && operator

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following button with [disabled] property.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary center-block" (click)="sign(sf.value)"
        [disabled]="validateInsuredFirstName(firstName.value) && validateInsuredLastName(lastName.value)">Sign Application</button>
```

But looks like only the first part of the && operator is always evaluated. Looks like it doesn't care about the second part of the expression : validateInsuredLastName(lastName.value).

Is there a way that we can get [disabled] to evaluate the whole expression ?

Comment: That's the way [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) with the [Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) operator works. If the first part is falsey, the second part isn't evaluated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe give us a truth table to explain the expected result.

Comment: As suggested in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101081/1009922), you can try `[disabled]="!!(func1(value1) & func2(value2))"` (with a single `&`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid short-circuited evaluation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100962/how-to-avoid-short-circuited-evaluation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your conditions in a dedicated function (`[disabled]="isValidatedFullName"`...) which returns false or true

Comment: I tried that earlier and it works. But I was wondering if there is a way to get the && operator working in this case ?

Comment: You can try with `valid` form. Normally `&&` works if both are invalid. Also, I think you should use an OR in this case, because you don't want to sign application if there is not `firstname` OR `lastname`